# Twofish password encryption in Silverstripe?

Tags: php, encryption, hash, silverstripe, twofish

is there a way how to use Twofish algorithm to hash passwords in Silverstripe? It doesn't  look that it's natively supported.

There is a way how to extend PasswordEncryptor probably.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment the [default is Blowfish](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/security#passwords).

Up until version 3.0 you could add your own algorithms via `register()`. Since 3.1 you will need to use the (YAML based) [configuration system](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-PasswordEncryptor.html#26).

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as you said - extend the PasswordEncryptor class and `register()` it in _config.php or config.yml